# git checkout ignored files from other branch

Tags: git

I have two branches A and B. Normally I work on the B branch in which I have a bunch of ignored stuff (untracked files). Now I have had to switch to the A branch to do some testing. Right after changing from B to A, all the ignored files in the B branch are now visible on the A and blocking me to switch back to the previous branch saying:

> Error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by checkout:
>
> XXXX (some files)
>
> Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch by
>   checkout.

I tried to stash them, but the files are still there.

What can I do?

Comment: You need to use `git stash -u` to stash untracked files

Comment: Great..! If you post it I can vote +1, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use only `git stash`, your untracked files will be unaffected. If you want them to be stashed as well, you need to use

```
 git stash -u
```

or

```
 git stash --include-untracked
```